# redux-form: How to throw new SubmissionError in Promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, redux-form

I got two variants of code - want to throw SubmissionError (redux-form), in first code it works fine, and I got "Uncaught (in promise)" in second. Tried to fix second code. Can any one tell why the second code cant throw SubmissionError? Tried do it with reject, but its not work too. Is it possible to throw SubmissionError with `new Promise`?

```
handleSubmit = async (values) => {
  const { addItem, reset } = this.props;
  await addItem({ item: values }).catch ((e) => {
    throw new SubmissionError({ _error: e.message });
  });
}
```

second not works:

```
handleSubmit = (values) => {
    const { addItem, reset } = this.props;
    const promise = (item) => new Promise((resolve) => {
      addItem(item);
      resolve();
    });

    return promise(values).catch((e) => {
      throw new SubmissionError({ _error: e.message });
    });
  }
```

"addItem" function (if its needed):

```
export const addItem = ({ text }) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const url = routes.Url();
    const response = await axios.post(url, { item: { text } });
    dispatch(addItemSuccess({ item: response.data }));
   } catch (e) {
     throw e;
   }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm, I think the problem in that you don't await your the promise. You return promise instead of the promise result, as result your code is not sync and SubmissionError lost context

Try it:

```
handleSubmit = (values) => {
    const { addItem, reset } = this.props;
    const promise = (item) => new Promise((resolve) => {
      addItem(item);
      resolve();
    });

    return await promise(values).catch((e) => {
      throw new SubmissionError({ _error: e.message });
    });
  }
```

Exists alternative way to set async errors to the form via `stopSubmit`

```
handleSubmit = (values) => {
    const { addItem, reset } = this.props;
    const promise = (item) => new Promise((resolve) => {
      addItem(item);
      resolve();
    });

    return promise(values).catch((e) => {
      dispatch(stopSubmit('FORM_NAME', { _error: e.message }));
    });
  }
```